# Remove records from ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, collections

Rails: 4.2

Ruby: 2.2.3

I'm utilizing **performances** in a model and its class is: Performance::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

Prior to upgrading to Rails 4 from Rails 2, this method worked:

```
def remove_expired_performances
  performances.reject! {|performance| performance.date < Date.today}
end
```

Now, I'm getting an error that reject! is an invalid method for ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy. This makes sense since reject is not listed here: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html

What is the cleanest way in Rails 4 that I could achieve the same result (removing the records from the collection that are older than today's date)?

Note: I need to keep the object as ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy and named **performances**.

Comment: can you try the following (I want to know if you can call `.where` on a CollectionProxy object): `performances.where('date > current_date')` (`current_date` is a PostgreSQL function)

Comment: You cannot call where on a CollectionProxy object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your model `has_many :performances`

```
class Orchestra < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :performances
end
```

I think the simplest solution would be to cast `performances` to an Array and reject the expired ones.

```
# class Orchestra
def remove_expired_performances
  performances.to_a.reject {|performance| performance.date < Date.today}
end
```

A more efficient solution might be to avoid pulling expired Performances out of the database in the first place.

```
# in wherever your finder code lives
@performances = Orchestra.find(params[:id]).performances.where('date >= ?', Date.today)
```

Comment: I ended up having to convert it to an array (something I was hoping to avoid). Thank you for the suggestions!